# All the uses of わけ?

Tags: grammar, usage, expressions

Ok, I've come across a few expressions involving the word わけ　（訳）such as わけではない, to indicate that something differs from a notion the listener may have; わけがない, to indicate that there is no sense in something, and just ending the sentence with わけだ to indicate a conclusion. I was wondering how many more of these わけ expressions there are, and what they are.

Comment: I've edited to switch references to わけ rather than 訳. Writing this and things like はず in kana much more common in contemporary Japanese. Though, I think your question might end up being too broad / reference only if you want people just to list uses of わけ

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks. I just like the way the kanji looks :P.

Comment: We all do, but it drives the native speakers crazy at times.  hehehe...If you're interested in learning more about when to use them and when to leave them off, that's addressed a bit here: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15141/are-there-general-rules-on-when-to-use-kanji-vs-kana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what you've got listed there's also:

- わけが分からない, indicating that you don't know why something is happening
- もうしわけない／もうしわけありません, which is a formal way of apologizing (literally translated, it means "there is no excuse [for what happened]")