# In the context of 「では、また」 , is it wrong to write 「また」 as 「又」?

Tags: kanji

If I understand correctly, 「では、また」 is basically short for 「では、又{また}会{あ}いましょう」, in which case it's completely normal to write 「また」 as 「又」.

But is it very weird or even wrong to use the kanji in the shortened form?

Comment: This is a fairly rarely used kanji to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no strict rules when to use kanji and when to use kana. So ultimately, it is your decision.

Practically speaking, in my opinion, it is better to write it always as また.

---

FYI. Since the また in question is the adverb *again*, the following is not exactly relevant, but you may be interested. Following this recommendation, you should use 又は to mean *or*.

[An official recommendation](https://www.bunka.go.jp/kokugo_nihongo/sisaku/joho/joho/kijun/sanko/koyobun/pdf/kunrei.pdf) has the following: (emphasis mine; also this is just a recommendation and not strict rules to be followed.)

> オ 次のような接続詞は，原則として，仮名で書く。
>
> > 例 おって かつ したがって ただし ついては ところが
> > ところで **また** ゆえに

> ただし，次の４語は，原則として，漢字で書く。
>
> > 及び 並びに **又は** 若しくは

---

Related : [Are there general rules on when to use kanji vs. kana?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15141/are-there-general-rules-on-when-to-use-kanji-vs-kana)